# How to override the CSS !important property when the original file loads after the customized css file

Tags: javascript, css

When I looked up this query online, i did see a bunch of results, nothing that suited well with my case. I have a custom style sheet that overrides the original CSS for a datepicker css. Tthe datepikcer.css has a property !important set on the width:

```
.q-superdate-field {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

I want to re-write the width and add custom width to it, so i did this in my stylesheet:

```
.q-superdate-field{
    width: 150px !important;
}
```

but unfortunately it does not take my !important as the datepicker.css files loads after my css file and hence takes the last !important property. any ideas how to solve this?thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override an `!important` with another more specific `!important` such as targeting a parent of the class.

```
.q-superdate-wrapper .q-superdate-field {
    width: 150px !important;
}
```

Or any closest class.

```
.some-closest-class .q-superdate-field {
    width: 150px !important;
}
```

But if you have control over the order I would order custom CSS after any 3rd party libraries.